# Angular 2 material mat-chip change selected

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am trying update chip's selected property but getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error when changing binding property

HTML

```
<mat-chip-list>
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let w of weekDays" [selectable]="true"   color="accent" selected="{{w.value}}" (click)="toggleValue(w)">
            {{w.text}}</mat-chip>

        </mat-chip-list>
```

Component

```
 weekDays=[{text:"MON",value:true},{text:"TUE",value:false},{text:"WED",value:false},{text:"THU",value:false},{text:"FRI",value:false},{text:"SAT",value:false},{text:"SUN",value:false}]

 toggleValue(w){
     w.value = !w.value; //Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject **`ChangeDetectorRef`** into your component and manually update it

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and then,

```
toggleValue(w){
     w.value = !w.value;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks that seems to did the trick. but doesn't behave as expected. Only the last chip that I click is selected (has color=accent) even though all the clicked items has value=true.

does it allow to have multiple chips selected?

Comment: i think that seems to be an issue with your logic

Comment: i think there is no problem in logic as it updates the list properly which means I have list with multiple items whose values are true but ui only shows one chip selected.

Comment: is it possible to have multiple chips selected? if yes, what am I dong wrong with my logic?

Comment: If i remove chip container "mat-chip-list" then it works as expected but it takes away css style as well.  So I think its "mat-chip-list" that is somehow causing problem.

Comment: Got it working 

it needs [multiple]="true" in mat-chat-list to allow multiple selection.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, there is a `multiple` option that defaults to false.

When `multiple` is set to false, the `mat-chip-list` will behave like a set of radio buttons (update the selected values for all other chips to false when a new one is selected). This is what causes the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api

**To allow setting more than one option:**

`<mat-chip-list [multiple]="true">
     ...`